# Can't make Bootstrap Modal data-attributes work

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, custom-data-attribute

I spend data via data-attributes and I can not do it.
I found many examples in StackOverflow and followed the example of Bootstrap docs but can not get it to work.

The modal displays ok, but not load the data-attributes.
This is my code:

Button:

```
<a type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' data-titulo='<?php the_title(); ?>' data-contenido='<?php echo strip_tags($contenido) ?>' data-enlace='<?php echo post_permalink($ID); ?>'><i class='flaticon-new67'></i></a>
```

The variables work ok. Looking at the source code, load correctly.

The Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enviar Nota</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input id="titulo" type="text" name="titulo" value=""/>
                <input type="text" name="contenido" value=""/>
                <input type="text" name="enlace" value=""/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var titulo = $(e.relatedTarget).data('titulo');
    var contenido = $(e.relatedTarget).data('contenido');
    var enlace = $(e.relatedTarget).data('enlace');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body input[name="titulo"]').val(titulo);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body input[name="contenido"]').val(contenido);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-body input[name="enlace"]').val(enlace);
});
```

What is wrong in the code?

This is the PHP´s button output:

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-titulo="Los secretos de los tambos rentables" data-contenido="Arturo Scheidegger es un especialista en producción lechera reconocido internacionalmente. Disertó en las jornadas Tambo Líder organizadas por CLAAS, Forratec y la marca CHT Hansen en Villa María. Frente a un grupo de productores de punta, el asesor internacional abogó por la medicina productiva, la calidad del forraje y la capacitación de los equipos de trabajo.

&nbsp;

“El mínimo de vacas para que un tambo sea rentable es cada vez mayor”, aseguró Arturo Scheidegger en la jornada Tambo Líder que se realizó recientemente en Villa María, Córdoba, organizada por CLAAS, Forratec y la marca CHR Hansen a través de su distribuidor Villa Nueva. El especialista chileno fue el principal disertante de una reunión técnica en la que participaron establecimientos lecheros de distintas regiones del país pero con un denominador común: todos tienen un mínimo de 1.100 vacas en ordeño.

“Cuando comencé, hace casi 30 años, un tambo de 100 vacas era una lechería decentemente grande. Hoy el mínimo está por encima de las 500 vacas y a los productores que están por debajo de ese número les resulta difícil afrontar los costos de personal, de maquinaria, y de asesoramiento”, agregó Scheidegger. También comentó que en Estados Unidos ya se estima que sólo serán viables los tambos intensivos con más de 1.000 vacas en producción.

De todas formas, el especialista chileno consideró que la lechería mundial seguirá creciendo bajo los diferentes modelos de producción, tanto aquellos con base pastoril como los estabulados. Pero remarcó que existe una tendencia a que los sistemas intensivos de producción apunten a mayores escalas para lograr rentabilidad.

Estos comentarios quedaron avalados por los datos que a nivel internacional muestran que se reduce el número total de tambos pero crece el tamaño de los que permanecen en la actividad, basados en mayor número de vacas y con incorporación de nuevas maquinarias y mejores planteos forrajeros.

La presentación de Scheidegger se llamó “Secretos de la Estabulación”, e hizo hincapié en tres. El primero fue la `medicina productiva´, a la que adhiere y que comenzó en Estados Unidos alrededor de 1980 basada en una visión holística de la actividad lechera. “El principal objetivo de la medicina productiva es la salud económica y el bienestar del propietario del establecimiento”, indicó el doctor en ciencias veterinarias. “Para ello contamos con programas específicos que nos permiten realizar evaluaciones periódicas sobre la marcha de la producción del establecimiento. Estos sistemas nos alertan cuando nos estamos alejando de los objetivos para que pongamos en marcha las correcciones necesarias que nos permitan mantener en equilibrio la relación costo-beneficio de la actividad”.

El segundo secreto del asesor de establecimientos lecheros es la calidad del forraje “que tiene que ser buena ya que es la vía que tenemos para abaratar los costos de producción. Por lo tanto, nunca se termina de trabajar lo suficiente en calidad de forraje”. Y con ese marco puntualizó la necesidad de realizar una adecuada conservación de los forrajes, atendiendo cuidadosamente desde la siembra de los cultivos hasta el suministro a los animales.

Por último, enfatizó en la necesidad de armar equipos de trabajos capacitados y motivados. “Pude comprobar que tambos en iguales condiciones, de zona, asesor y sistema de producción, pueden mostrar resultados muy distintos según la capacidad y habilidad de su equipo de trabajo”.

“El desafío es mantener una actividad lechera eficiente, cuya rentabilidad le permita competir con otras producciones. Para ello, la gestión del equipo de trabajo es determinante”, resumió Scheidegger." data-enlace="http://saviacomunicacion.com.ar/test2014/sala_de_prensa/los-secretos-de-los-tambos-rentables/">
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP's output?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/VUZhL/, any error in the console? What about the php script?

Comment: I put the PHP´s output in the question.

Comment: The output for that one attribute looks perhaps improperly escaped (containing `"` and such - that could be causing an error.

Comment: How could I eliminate the `"` to test if that´s is the problem.

Comment: It's not the `"`, i eliminate and tried with one word, and still don't work.